# Return an object from a datalist

Tags: angular

I want an object to be selected by datalist, however, when selecting, I don't get the entire object, but only parts.
A solution that occurs to me would be that I enter the id as [value] and read the object again, but I find that variant extremely unpleasant.
Are there any other ways to get the object?

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">
    <input type="search" list="objects" formControlName="selectedObject" (change)=userInput() 
      class="form-control">
        <datalist id="objects">
          <option *ngFor="let o of obj" [value]="o.name">
            {{o.id}}, {{o.info}}
          </option>
        </datalist>
</form>
```

TS:

```
selectedObject: IObjects;

userInput() {
    console.log('this.myForm.value.selectedObject');         // Output: o.name (or without [value]: 
                                                                 o.id, o.info
    console.log('this.myForm.value.selectedObject.name');    // Output: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the output as `o.name` try setting the output `<option *ngFor="let o of obj" [value]="o">` then the entire object will be able to access in the controller to see relevent properties of the object.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">
    <input type="search" list="objects" formControlName="selectedObject" (change)=userInput() 
      class="form-control">
        <datalist id="objects">
          <option *ngFor="let o of obj" [value]="o">
            {{o.id}}, {{o.info}}
          </option>
        </datalist>
</form>
```

**As another examples :**

**HTML :**

```
<select class="custom-select" (change)="changeCity($event)" formControlName="cityName">
              <option value="">Choose your city</option>
              <option *ngFor="let city of City" [ngValue]="city"> 
              {{city.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

**In the controller.ts :**

```
export class AppComponent {
  isSubmitted = false;

  // City Names
  City: any = [{ id: 1, name: "Florida" }, { id: 2, name: "XXXX" }];

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {}

  /*Form */
  registrationForm = this.fb.group({
    cityName: ["", [Validators.required]]
  });

  // Choose city using select dropdown
  changeCity(e) {
    alert(
      "ID :" +
        this.registrationForm.value.cityName.id +
        " NAME :" +
        this.registrationForm.value.cityName.name
    );
  }
}
```

Please find the stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-dropdown-reactive-form-q7wqf5).

Comment: that doesn't work, it returns an error message, which says that it still don't know this.myForm.value.selectedObject.name and in the preview of the datalist the object is shown as [object Object]

Comment: Did you check the stackblitz?

Comment: Basically [object Object] stands for the selected data object you can access the relevent properties accordingly using dot annotation

Comment: I changed it in my code and checked it with visual studio code and ng serve, I don't use stackblitz ^^"

Comment: Stackblitz is there basically to get an idea of the solution provided.

Comment: Also the solution I provide is working properly. according to the live example given.

Comment: thank you, the example worked, it seems to be a big difference to use <datalist> or <select>

Comment: The example shows `<select><option></option></select>` and not `<input list='listId'><datalist id='listId'><option></option></datalist>`